# Android - Extend a Bitmap to use as MapMarker

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-image, android-mapview

I want to use downloaded images as markers on a MapView. I images are all squares but I would like the bottom to also extend to form a triangle marking the exact point.

My approach was to create a canvas which is slightly larger than the image. Then, draw the bitmap on to the canvas and then somehow pick the color from the bottom of the bitmap and draw a triangular shape from the horizontal center of the image to the bottom of the canvas. Something like this...

[image]

As you might guess I'm stuck with the last part. So far I have....

```
Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(markerBitmap.getWidth(), markerBitmap.getHeight()+10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
// The 10 pixels will be the so called "pin"
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(markerBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
// Can figure out how to draw the 10 px bottom using the color from markerBitmap
```

Help !!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you want to create the images dynamically? If not, why don't you create them using a graphics editing program, save them as png's or 9-patch images and then simply assign it to the Drawable that's used for the marker.

Comment: Yes. The images are downloaded. I got to this problem by using the shown image and overlaying the downloaded images to fit onto it.... but the blue clashes pretty badly with some of them. I reckon it would be the same problem with most other colors so I want to use the color from the actual image to make the marker.